# PayPal SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, sigabrt

I am trying to implement the Paypal SDK into my iOS app. I copied the code exactly from the Readme instructions, imported the files, and linked my button to my action but when I clicked the button it gives me a "Thread 1 signal:SIGABRT" error and crashes.

Here is the Paypal code in my .m files:

```
- (IBAction)pay {

// Create a PayPalPayment
PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"39.95"];
payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
payment.shortDescription = @"Product";

// Check whether payment is processable.
if (!payment.processable) {
    // If, for example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was empty, then
    // this payment would not be processable. You would want to handle that here.
}


// Provide a payerId that uniquely identifies a user within the scope of your system,
// such as an email address or user ID.
NSString *aPayerId = @"someone@someone.com";

// Create a PayPalPaymentViewController with the credentials and payerId, the PayPalPayment
// from the previous step, and a PayPalPaymentDelegate to handle the results.
PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:@"MY-CLIENT-ID-HERE"
                                                                receiverEmail:@"MY-EMAIL-HERE"
                                                                      payerId:aPayerId
                                                                      payment:payment
                                                                     delegate:self];

// Present the PayPalPaymentViewController.
[self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - PayPalPaymentDelegate methods

- (void)payPalPaymentDidComplete:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
// Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment.
[self verifyCompletedPayment:completedPayment];

// Dismiss the PayPalPaymentViewController.
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel {
// The payment was canceled; dismiss the PayPalPaymentViewController.
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)verifyCompletedPayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
// Send the entire confirmation dictionary
NSData *confirmation = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:completedPayment.confirmation
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:nil];

// Send confirmation to your server; your server should verify the proof of payment
// and give the user their goods or services. If the server is not reachable, save
// the confirmation and try again later.
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Try to localize where in the `pay` method the crash occurs. I would do this by commenting out various parts of the code in a systematic way. I would start by commenting out the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` line. See if it's the view controller causing the crash or something else and get back to us.

Comment: When i removed that line and tap the button it does not crash but it does not do anything, just stays at that screen.

Comment: I don't know the SDK, so hopefully someone else will be able to help you. I've up-voted you for visibility. In the meantime, here's what I would do. I took a quick look at the SDK. It seems like you've got the code set up correctly, but apart from the code there are a lot of setup steps. If you haven't already, I would verify each part of the project setup, using a checklist. It's possible you missed something. Good luck!

SDK: `https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK`

Comment: I contacted Paypal about the issue and they looked at my console log and said it has something to do with Google Analytics, do you know of anything with the two that would be causing an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You know what?

cuz you use decimal number on you currency.
so you need do something in this code

---

// Check whether payment is processable.

if (!payment.processable) {

```
// If, for example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was empty, then
// this payment would not be processable. You would want to handle that here.
```

}

---

If you in debug point you can find a keyword in payment, display, it's mean your currency will change to 40.0. 
Try it.